# Server-side Backbone.Model?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, server-side, backbone-model

I wanted to ask if anyone has tried to create a Backbone Model on the server?

I appreciate Backbone is mainly for the client side and on a previous question about this no one recommended Backbone for the server...

I'm not creating a MVC website or designing REST services, and looking more to building something similar to a virtual Aggregation Server.  A Backbone model would be ideal for me to initialise data feeds and stores based on events - and push data based on those events.

The trouble I have is that Backbone is dependent on jQuery.  I am not using Backbone.View - so wondered if there was a way to use Backbone.Model on the server side in a requirejs.config kind of way?

I've looked at things like Rendr and its not suitable.

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/backbone-model

Comment: Nope....That package still uses jQuery

Comment: I can use Backbone.Model on server side without jQuery (just save method and other which used jQuery.ajax to send XHR request won't work). Update: you can also assign your own fake jQuery like this: `Backbone.$ = { ajax: function() {} }`

Comment: Do you use a different .sync method or have a different set up?  I can't seem to get Backbone up and running as it talks about jQuery - which won't work on the server.